# Why is my R Code running fine on a virtual cluster, but not on my physical machine?

Tags: r, rstudio, cluster-computing, data-science, anova

I just have a quick question about my code. I am having some discrepancies between the code I ran on a virtual cluster running RStudio and the code I ran on my physical machine. 
We had to create a R- Markdown file in order to reproduce the ANOVA table. I ran my code on the cluster just fine.

Here is my code:

````
```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
wine <- read.csv("wine.csv")

cultivar <- as.factor( wine[, "Cultivar"])
alcohol <- wine[, "Alcohol"]

alcohol.list <- split(alcohol, cultivar)


alcohol.list

$`1`
 [1] 14.23 13.20 13.16 14.37 13.24 14.20 14.39 14.06 14.83 13.86 14.10 14.12 13.75 14.75 14.38 13.63 14.30 13.83 14.19 13.64
[21] 14.06 12.93 13.71 12.85 13.50 13.05 13.39 13.30 13.87 14.02 13.73 13.58 13.68 13.76 13.51 13.48 13.28 13.05 13.07 14.22
[41] 13.56 13.41 13.88 13.24 13.05 14.21 14.38 13.90 14.10 13.94 13.05 13.83 13.82 13.77 13.74 13.56 14.22 13.29 13.72

$`2`
 [1] 12.37 12.33 12.64 13.67 12.37 12.17 12.37 13.11 12.37 13.34 12.21 12.29 13.86 13.49 12.99 11.96 11.66 13.03 11.84 12.33
[21] 12.70 12.00 12.72 12.08 13.05 11.84 12.67 12.16 11.65 11.64 12.08 12.08 12.00 12.69 12.29 11.62 12.47 11.81 12.29 12.37
[41] 12.29 12.08 12.60 12.34 11.82 12.51 12.42 12.25 12.72 12.22 11.61 11.46 12.52 11.76 11.41 12.08 11.03 11.82 12.42 12.77
[61] 12.00 11.45 11.56 12.42 13.05 11.87 12.07 12.43 11.79 12.37 12.04

$`3`
 [1] 12.86 12.88 12.81 12.70 12.51 12.60 12.25 12.53 13.49 12.84 12.93 13.36 13.52 13.62 12.25 13.16 13.88 12.87 13.32 13.08
[21] 13.50 12.79 13.11 13.23 12.58 13.17 13.84 12.45 14.34 13.48 12.36 13.69 12.85 12.96 13.78 13.73 13.45 12.82 13.58 13.40
[41] 12.20 12.77 14.16 13.71 13.40 13.27 13.17 14.13
````

```
oneway <- function(z)
  {
   ni <- sapply(z, length)
   yi_bar <- sapply(z, mean)
   s2i <- sapply(z, sd)
   Y_bar <- mean(unlist(z))
   g <- length(z)
   N <-length(unlist(z))

   Within_SS = sum((ni-1) * s2i^2)
   Between_SS = sum(ni *((yi_bar)-(Y_bar))^2)

   DF_Within = (N - g)
   DF_Between = (g - 1)

   list("WithinSS" = Within_SS, "BetweenSS"= Between_SS, "DFWithin" = DF_Within, "DFBetween" = DF_Between)

 }


 alcohol.aov <- oneway(alcohol.list)

 alcohol.aov
```

```
oneway.table <- function(z)
 {
   Mean_SSW <- z[[1]]/z[[3]]
   Mean_SSB <- z[[2]]/z[[4]]
   F_value <- (Mean_SSB/Mean_SSW)
   P_value <- pf(F_value, DF_Between, DF_Within, lower.tail = FALSE)

   anova <- matrix(c( z[[4]], z[[3]], z[[2]], z[[1]], Mean_SSB, Mean_SSW, F_value, NA, P_value, NA), ncol =5)
   dimnames(anova) <- list("Group" = c("cultivar", "Residuals"), "ANOVA" = c("DF", "Sum_Sq", "Mean_Sq", "F_value", "P_value"))

   printCoefmat(anova, signif.stars = TRUE, has.Pvalue = TRUE, digits = 3, na.print="")

 }

 oneway.table(alcohol.aov)
```

The code I did worked just fine on the virtual cluster and I was able to reproduce this ANOVA table:

```
               DF  Sum_Sq Mean_Sq F_value P_value    
cultivar    2.000  70.795  35.397     135  <2e-16 ***
Residuals 175.000  45.859   0.262                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**However when I ran it on my local machine, I got this error message:**

```
Error in pf(F_value, DF_Between, DF_Within, lower.tail = FALSE) : object 'DF_Between' not found
```

**I understand that my DF_Between is not found in my second chunk of code, but why would it work in the cluster and not on my local machine?**

Also I re ran my code, this time adding in the definitions to the variables:

```
oneway.table <- function(z)
 {

   g <- length(z)
   N <-length(unlist(z))

   DF_Within <- (N - g)
   DF_Between <- (g - 1)

   Mean_SSW <- z[[1]]/z[[3]]
   Mean_SSB <- z[[2]]/z[[4]]
   F_value <- (Mean_SSB/Mean_SSW)
   P_value <- pf(F_value, DF_Between, DF_Within, lower.tail = FALSE)



   anova <- matrix(c( z[[4]], z[[3]], z[[2]], z[[1]], Mean_SSB, Mean_SSW, F_value, NA, P_value, NA), ncol =5) 
   dimnames(anova) <- list("Group" = c("cultivar", "Residuals"), "ANOVA" = c("DF", "Sum_Sq", "Mean_Sq", "F_value",           "P_value")) 

   printCoefmat(anova, signif.stars = TRUE, has.Pvalue = TRUE, digits = 3, na.print="")

 }

 oneway.table(alcohol.aov)
```

But now, my output looks like this:

```
       ANOVA
Group            DF  Sum_Sq Mean_Sq F_value P_value
  cultivar    2.000  70.795  35.397     135        
  Residuals 175.000  45.859   0.262
```

No significant level stars or any P_Value, If anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you give us a sample of `alcohol.list`? What should it look like? In your first attempt it didn't work because `pf(F_value, DF_Between, DF_Within, lower.tail = FALSE)` expected `DF_Between` and `DF_Within` to be provided either explicitly or by inheritance yet it's not.

Comment: yes :   I will edit my original post and add alcohol.list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Here's how you can fix it without the Explanation.

Creating a reproducible example:

```
alcohol.list <- list("1"=c(14.2, 13.2), 
                     "2"=c(12.3, 12.3),
                     "3"=c(12.8, 12.9))
alcohol.list
```

Your untouched `oneway` function:

```
oneway <- function(z)
  {
   ni <- sapply(z, length)
   yi_bar <- sapply(z, mean)
   s2i <- sapply(z, sd)
   Y_bar <- mean(unlist(z))
   g <- length(z)
   N <-length(unlist(z))

   Within_SS = sum((ni-1) * s2i^2)
   Between_SS = sum(ni *((yi_bar)-(Y_bar))^2)

   DF_Within = (N - g)
   DF_Between = (g - 1)

   list("WithinSS" = Within_SS, "BetweenSS"= Between_SS, "DFWithin" = DF_Within, "DFBetween" = DF_Between)

 }


 alcohol.aov <- oneway(alcohol.list)
```

Finally, your `oneway.table` with `p.value`:

```
oneway.table <- function(z)
 {
   Mean_SSW <- z$WithinSS/z$DFWithin
   Mean_SSB <- z$BetweenSS/z$DFBetween
   F_value <- (Mean_SSB/Mean_SSW)
   P_value <- pf(F_value, z$DFBetween, z$DFWithin, lower.tail = FALSE)

   anova <- matrix(c(z[[4]], z[[3]], z[[2]], z[[1]], Mean_SSB, Mean_SSW, F_value, NA, P_value, NA), ncol =5)
   dimnames(anova) <- list("Group" = c("cultivar", "Residuals"), "ANOVA" = c("DF", "Sum_Sq", "Mean_Sq", "F_value", "P_value"))

   printCoefmat(anova, signif.stars = TRUE, has.Pvalue = TRUE, digits = 3, na.print="")

 }
oneway.table(alcohol.aov)
```

Returns:

```
             DF Sum_Sq Mean_Sq F_value P_value  
cultivar  2.000  1.990   0.995    5.91   0.091 .
Residuals 3.000  0.505   0.168                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

### Explanation

In the following code, `DF_Between` was not created prior to the `pf()` method call. In fact `DF_Within` was also not created and doesn't exist in that scope.

This can work for example:

```
# create DF_Between and DF_Within first and pass in all three as arguments
oneway.table <- function(z, DF_Between, DF_Within){
   Mean_SSW <- z[[1]]/z[[3]]
   Mean_SSB <- z[[2]]/z[[4]]
   F_value <- (Mean_SSB/Mean_SSW)
   P_value <- pf(F_value, DF_Between, DF_Within, lower.tail = FALSE)

   ...
 }
```

This can also work:

```
oneway.table <- function(z){
   Mean_SSW <- z[[1]]/z[[3]]
   Mean_SSB <- z[[2]]/z[[4]]
   F_value <- (Mean_SSB/Mean_SSW)
   # provided that z is a list with the two elements
   P_value <- pf(F_value, z$DF_Between, z$DF_Within, lower.tail = FALSE)

   ...
 }
```

This works also:

```
oneway.table <- function(z){
   Mean_SSW <- z[[1]]/z[[3]]
   Mean_SSB <- z[[2]]/z[[4]]
   F_value <- (Mean_SSB/Mean_SSW)
   # create DF_Between and DF_Within directly in here
   g <- length(z)
   N <-length(unlist(z))
   DF_Within <- (N - g)
   DF_Between <- (g - 1)
   P_value <- pf(F_value, DF_Between, DF_Within, lower.tail = FALSE)

   ...
 }
```

Whichever way you chose, you just need to understand the **lexical scoping** rules that R uses. Saving you the long and tedious explanation, this is how it goes:

> The [search process that occurs](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/scoping-rules-of-r.html) goes as follows:
>
> - If the value of a symbol is not found in the environment in which a
>     function was defined, then the search is continued in the parent
>     environment.
> - The search continues down the sequence of parent
>     environments until we hit the top-level environment; this usually the
>     global environment (workspace) or the namespace of a package.
> - After the top-level environment, the search continues down the search list
>     until we hit the empty environment.

In the environment of your local machine, it first search for `DF_Between` and `DF_Within` in the environment in which that function was defined, `oneway.table`. There it wasn't found, so `DF_Between` and `DF_Within` are searched for in the parent environment, and there it wasn't found as well, and it hits the empty environment.

But on your cluster, it first search for `DF_Between` and `DF_Within` in the environment in which that function was defined, `oneway.table`. There it wasn't found, so `DF_Between` and `DF_Within` are searched for in the parent environment and there it was found. So no error or exception was raised.

You can confirm this by running `ls()` to print and confirm that `DF_Within` and `DF_Between` did exist in the parent environment on the cluster and not on your local machine.

Comment: @Tariq335, please look at the Solution in the answer. Feel free to skip the Explanation section if lexical scoping only adds to the confusion. Let me know if its helpful or if you need further clarifications

Comment: I appreciate this a lot onlyphantom!

Comment: @Tariq335 Glad to be helpful. If the answer solves your problem consider accepting it as answer!

Comment: Is there a way I can give you credit for your response? Sorry, a bit new to this site @onlyphantom

Comment: No problem! There is a tick next to each answer. If you find an answer helpful consider marking it as accepted. It helps others who use the site to find answers too!